# API for panel applets on eOS Pantheon?

Tags: bash, python, development, elementary-os, api

Is there any API (esp python or bash) to append new applets on eOS Pantheon's panel?

I can't find proper documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got your question straight but, to get an application to appear on Elementary's panel (also known as slingshot-launcher) all you need to do is to create an .desktop file in the folder ~/.local/share/applications/. I suggest you to create the .desktop launcher based on one of those already listed there.